# How to populate one drop down with another using ajx, php and html

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

i want to populate a dropdownlist based on an input from another using ajax. But have head a deadend and can't figure out the problem. It uses company names to open up a dropdown list of mobile phone made by that company.

This is the source php file:

```
 <body>
 <div class="ex">
 <form id="mob1" >
  <label></br> Select Mobile 1:</label>
  <label></br> --Company-- <label>
  <select id="d1mob1" onchange="getmob(this.value)">
  <?php 
    $q1=mysqli_query($con,"select distinct compName from umobile order by compName ASC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q1)) 
    {
        $options .="<option value=\"". $row['compName'] ."\">" . $row['compName'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo $options;
  ?>
  </select>
  <label class="ey" name="mlabel"></br> --Mobile--<label>

  <select id="d2mob1" >
  <?php 
    if($q2=mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT DISTINCT mobname FROM umobile WHERE compName=? "))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q2,"s",$comp);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($q2);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($q2,$r);
    }   

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($q2))
    {
        $name .="<option value=\"".$r."\" >".$r."</option>";        
    }
    echo $name;
?>
</select>

</form>
</div>

 </body>
```

This is the getmob php file being referred to inorder to query the mobile name :

```
  <?php 
$name="";
$comp=$_GET['d1mob1'];
if($q2=mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT DISTINCT mobname FROM umobile WHERE compName=? "))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q2,"s",$comp);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($q2);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($q2,$r);
}   

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($q2))
{
    $name .="<option value=\"".$r."\" >".$r."</option>";        
}
echo $name;
   ?>
```

and finally this is javascript being used in the dropdownlist:

```
  function getmob(compname)
  {
    var strURL="getmob.php?d1mob1="+compname;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    if (req)
    {
     req.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
       if (req.readyState == 4) // only if "OK"
       {
         if (req.status == 200)
         {
           document.getElementById('mlabel').innerHTML=req.responseText;
         } else {
          alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
        }
      }
    }
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send(null);
  }
  }
```

What am i missing ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById('mlabel')`??? r you want to put the responseText in `d2mob1`?

Comment: oppps!! i'm new to ajax. i'd been beating my head over that for a while now. Just didn't notice that. Thanks!!